# Displaying the picture on the browser

Tags: php

The following code returns the urls of the pics that has to be displayed:

```
$link = "http://example.com/ext/lib/exe/process.phpt=87458+52&w=466&h=471&:forum_pic:queue_hasb_bunny_khd_tyun_02300.jpg, Imm processing,http://example.com/storage/high resolution/i-white bunny-tyun.jpg,only cash payment,process after christmas, handle with care notification, date: 2-5-2015";
$extraFieldData = explode(',',$link);
 $images= array();
 foreach($extraFieldData as $efd){
  if(strpos($efd,'jpg')!== false){
   $images[] = $efd;}
    }
   foreach ($images as $i){ 
    echo $i;
     }
   <img src= "<?php echo $i;?>"/>
```

The code works fine to echo the urls of the pictures but when I try to display the urls in the browser, only one picture is displayed and not the other one. How to get both the urls to display?

Comment: Umm, you realize images are displayed on an HTML page with the `<img src="foo.jpg" />` tag, right?

Comment: Yes within the img src tag, <img src= "<?php echo $i;?>"/>

Comment: The urls are remote or local?

Comment: @vicky Right, but there's no `img` tag anywhere in your code...

Comment: Is `.../files:sample...` supposed to be `.../files/sample...` in the second img?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I didnt paste that part of the code in the question, have edited to show the img tag in the question

Comment: @macinnir: The urls are local

Comment: @Sean: sorry the link was just a sample one

Comment: You should always post your actual code to minize the back and forth of "well that's not actually my problem."

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: got the point, henceforth will follow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it shows only one image (and the image URLs are correct), you're doing it outside of the loop and `$i` has the value of the last image iterated from the `$images` array.

For example:

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
foreach($arr as $a) {

}

echo $a;
```

This will output `four`.